# Unable to make an android project with a .jar compile

Tags: java, android, jar

Really looked all over the place, but I'm at pretty much a deadlock. I'm currently unable to compile any Android Project that uses an external .jar. Even if this is just an empty project it always returns the same error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1.

Am I completely missing something? Are native-java (Netbeans) jars incompatible for Android?

Currently the process is: 
- copy the .jar to the libs folder
- resync gradle
- clean rebuild
- try to run
- death

Edit: For those of you who should ever run into this wall. If you have pure JAVA jars that contain pre 6.0 JDK code and compile it with a higher level JDK, Android wil not recognize it and give you that specific error. Compiling my netbeans project with JDK 5.0 fixed my problem and my Android projects finally run now.

In Netbeans, right click the libraries folder in your project > properties > sources and under Source/Binary Format, select JDK 5 (or lower). Your Android project should compile now with your jar.

Comment: check the answer below, it worked for me

Comment: Didnt for me unfortunatly.. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: what problem still are you facing? also try to create and experiment on new project

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you need to update the you sdk to the current version of
  Android api like Android M (Api level 23) and also download the latest version   of gradle. (i.e. use everthing latest and utilize the hard work of android sdk developers because that's for helping the android developers and android users)
- and also use that for your app target version
- Then restart android with invalidate cache and restart option
- And then you should add .jar file to libs folder then click option
  add as library

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line of code in your `build.gradle` file?:

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

And where is your `libs` folder located? It should be in the root folder of the module, not the whole prject.

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.iml
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── libs  <----- check this
│   │   ├── greendao-1.3.7.jar
│   │   ├── httpcore-4.3-beta1.jar
│   │   ├── mimecraft-1.1.1.jar
│   │   └── volley.jar
│   ├── proguard-rules.pro
│   └── src
│       ├── androidTest
│       └── main
├── android
│   ├── app
│   │   └── annotations.xml
│   └── content
│       └── annotations.xml
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── build.gradle
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── project-name.iml
├── local.properties
├── settings.gradle
└── settings.gradle.orig
```

Also, in my experience, most of the time `java finished with non-zero exit code` error is related to resources or other non-java related stuff. You should check out `Gradle console` and look for red lines, they contain actual error messages that you can check and fix.

[image: gradle console screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My code was actually pure Java in itself, but I found some issues related to compiling pre 5.0 java code with a higher level compiler. It comes down to those "old" classes not being known by Dalvik's Virtual Machine. I re-compiled my .jar using the 5.0 JDK instead of the current one, and that fixed it. Thank god